# Apache CXF without web.xml with Swagger UI

Tags: cxf, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using CXF for RESTful web services without web.xml. All CXF and rest endpoint configuration stored in xml files(managed by Spring). Now I'm trying to implement Swagger in my service. I've added SwaggerFeature to my jax-rs config:

```
<jaxrs:features>
       <ref bean="swaggerFeature"/>
</jaxrs:features>
```

So now pure JSON description for my endpoint (`http://localhost:8080/api-docs`) works fine. But I have no idea how to connect Swagger UI to my project. All examples that I've seen are using web.xml. Is it possible to connect Swagger UI without this configuration? Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT.** Now this problem is solved. CXF uses embedded jetty server. I just added custom `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler` to `JettyHTTPServerEngine` bean declaration and configured it. Thus static content was exposed to web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swagger-ui has nothing to do with the web.xml. If you're hosting it as part of your application, you only need to modify the index.html and point it to your `/api-docs`. If you keep it separate, you still need to modify the index.html, but you also need to enable CORS support in your application. Both swagger-ui and swagger-core contain more information on that.

Comment: Ok, i've modified index.html, but also I need a servlet that accepts http request and points to that index.html? I do not fully understand how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: No need for a servlet. Application servers/Web Containers are perfectly capable of exposing static content. How you'd set it up really depends on the way you build your application (manually, maven, gradle and so on).

Comment: I use Maven for building.

Comment: Then you would normally throw the static content directly under the webapp dir.

Comment: I do not use Web container for exposing Web services. Actually i have Java service wrapper for this... Still stuck with this thing.

Comment: Then how do you expose your CXF servlet?

Comment: As far as I understand, CXF servlet configured implicitly in my app. I just created some CXF beans, and when my app launches, CXF creates servlet automatically ( some magic happens ). The one thing I'm sure that there is no explicit configuration for CXF servlet.

Comment: How do you launch the app? There has to be something there. Even if it's low level Grizzly, there has to be *something*.

Comment: Using exec-maven plugin(mvn exec:java in command line). It runs main method, which invoke Spring applicationContext and runs JavaServiceWrapper daemon process.

Comment: Well, then, you need to find the way serve static content the way you serve your servlets. If you don't modify the question with proper details, nobody would be able to assist.

Comment: Thanks Ron for your responses, now this problem is solved. See edits in original question.